# AngularJS implement element's before method without jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a simple way to implement **before** method for DOM manipulation without jQuery in my AngularJS directive?

jQuery way is:

```
$element.before($insertedBeforeElement);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To do it without jQuery but with angular's jqLite:

```
$element.parent()[0].insertBefore($insertedBeforeElement[0], $element[0]);
```

Comment: @KarlMorrison **$element** is a jqLite object that is a wrapper above the DOM node of type `Node.ELEMENT_NODE`  and is obtained using the `angular.element` function.

Comment: It looks like `.insertBefore()` does not exist on a jqLite element.  here are the docs with the available methods for Angular: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite

Comment: @Chris Barr `.insertBefore()` is a native method of the DOM Node.

Comment: @ArtemPlatonov Ha, well so it is! I was not aware.  I was getting errors trying this method yesterday, I'll have to give it a closer look now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

jqLite does support `.after()` so you can use that to do a little shuffling.

```js
$element.after($insertedBeforeElement); //add it after
$insertedBeforeElement.after($element); //now switch the positions
```